# What defines weightlessness feeling during a fall?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, acceleration, harmonic-oscillator, free-body-diagram

So I know that we feel weightless during a free fall as there's no normal force acting on us or my other way of thinking is that considering a lift and both lift and I fall with $g$ then no normal force between us to make me feel my weight and if lift is accelerating up then I will feel my weight more as I am experiencing more normal force from lift.

Now what if I am moving with upward velocity and gravity pulling us down, I should still feel weightless it just I am moving away from lift and still no contact so I will still feel weightless.

So even if I have more acceleration than $g$ and have no contact with any surface means experiencing no normal force I should feel weightless?

So I have a doubt in a question of simple harmonic motion.

> A man of mass 60 kg is standing on a platform which is executing simple harmonic motion in a vertical plane. The displacement from the main position where is his $y = 0.5 sin(2πxt)$. The minimum value of $x$ for which the man will feel weightlessness at highest point

The answer suggest that at highest point it will be the extreme point of simple harmonic motion so at highest point there will be maximum acceleration which will be equal to w²A(absolute value)(here w is angular frequency and A amplitude)
So w²a= g (they put the values and got the answer)

But I think that value of x doesn't matter as long as we don't experience a normal force
Correct me if I am thinking wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> So even if I have more acceleration than g and have no contact with any surface means experiencing no normal force I should feel weightless?

Yes, almost. The key part to weightlessness is "no normal force" (and no other non-gravitational forces such as tension from a rope, or air resistance). You could still be in contact with a surface as long as the surface has the same velocity and acceleration as you do. For example, you might be in a spacecraft where both you and the spacecraft are in free fall. You could be in contact with a wall of the spacecraft, but as long as it exerts no normal force on you then you will feel weightless.

The difference between gravity and other forces is that gravity acts equally on all parts of your body. That is why you do not feel the effect of gravity in free fall - what we think of as a feeling of weight is in fact the normal force from the ground that opposes gravity. You would only feel gravity directly if the direction or strength of the gravitational field varied significantly from one part of your body to another - and that is not likely to happen unless you have a close encounter with a black hole.

As long as the only force acting on you is gravity then the magnitude of your acceleration does not matter. You could be in free fall in low Earth orbit, where your acceleration is still essentially $1g$. Or you could be in free fall a few miles above the surface of the Moon, where your acceleration is $\frac 1 6g$. Or you could be in free fall a few miles above the surface of the Moon, where your acceleration is $\frac 1 6g$. Or you could be plummeting towards a giant planet with an acceleration of many times $g$. All of these free fall scenarios will feel the same to you.

And the point of the platform problem is that the man will feel weightless when the platform underneath him is accelerating downwards with an acceleration of $1g$. The question is using $x$ (which I assume is fixed) for the frequency of the SHM, which is somewhat confusing as we usually think of $x$ as denoting a displacement. It would be clearer if it used $f$ for frequency, so the equation for displacement would be $y = 0.5 \sin(2 \pi ft)$.

Comment: "As long as the only force acting on you is gravity then the magnitude of your acceleration does not matter". Okat but what if we are on earth only but as we are falling , some sort of a rope is tied to our leg and it is also pulling us down. What i mean is that we have acceleration >g (no surface below us) but acceleration is not entirely due to gravity.    Clearly, the distribution of the *extra* force, say, tension of the rope is not uniform. Will we feel weightlessness in that case?

Comment: @PinkAura If the rope is exerting a force on you then  you will feel that force and you will not be in free fall.

Comment: @PinkAura ... and if the rope is tied around your foot it will feel as if you are hanging upside down held up by a rope around your foot.